# Latest android studio 2.3.3 text issue

Tags: android-studio

In the palette of android studio 2.3.3, the text palette provides us only with "Plain Text", whereas in youtube tutorials, "Small Text", "Large Text" are also provided. So how do we increase the size of our text now?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `fontSize` property of `TextView` either in **Properties** part of Design tab.

[image]

or set it directly in XML using `android:textSize="20sp"`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/post_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" /
```